# Using Node to set Windows PATH variable?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to first check if a folder is part of the %PATH% variable, and if not, add it. Unfortunately this issue is really hard to look up because all the Google results are inevitably about npm's own inclusion in %PATH%. And it's a very slow issue to test and experiment with because refreshing the %PATH% involves a 2-3 minute reboot cycle.

`require('child_process').exec('setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\\testpath"')` only seems to add `C`, and nothing else. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick run of Your line and added some console.logs:

```
stdout:
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

stderr:
WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.
```

I have also tried adding /M and it did not help.

What appears to be the issue is the truncation to 1024 characters. A quick research gives me this:

https://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx

It seems that that You can force PATH to have more than 1024 characters by writing to the registry directly, but it may cause some applications to crash and is unadvised.